# Android app created by unity3d is more likely to crash after playing a video

Tags: android, video, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an android app which can play videos and view models. I decide to use unity3d to finish it.
I set the 2 functions in several scenes and each scene has its funciton. I will enter different scene, when I want to see different video or model. If I see models, no matter how many models, it can run successfully. But if the app is more likely to crashed when I view models after I see a video(maybe only 10M).
I use `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie()` to play videos in unity3d. The error in android are as following.

> 11-05 22:33:51.589 14794-14807/? I/Adreno: DequeueBuffer: dequeueBuffer failed
>   11-05 22:33:51.609 14794-14807/? W/Adreno-GSL: : ioctl fd 29 code 0xc0140933 (IOCTL_KGSL_TIMESTAMP_EVENT) failed: errno 24 Too many open files
>   11-05 22:33:51.609 14794-14807/? W/Adreno-GSL: : (1e, 14, 92844) fail 24 Too many open files
>   11-05 22:33:51.619 14794-14807/? E/Surface: dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -2147483646

It maybe there are too may open files? But there are only a video and it should has been removed from the memory when I change scene in unity3d. If you have any ideas about it, Please contact me. Thank you very much!

**Added**: Actually I think my question is the same as [the question](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-when-changing-scene-after-handheld-dot-playfullscreenmovie-was-called-app-crashes-on-htc-one-m9-plus). Is it a Bug of Unity3d?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(ShowMotion());
}

IEnumerator ShowMotion()
{
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("motion.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();//not writing the second yield return causes a failure.
}
```

Comment: Why I need to tuse Coroutine in this situation? Could you give me some reasons? Why there are 2 yield return?

Comment: the reason for coroutine is playing a fullscreen movie blocks your code, and the reason for two yields is a mystery!

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work for my problem. I think it's the same for me to call `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("motion.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);` directly. Isn't it?

Comment: Actually I think my question is the same as [the question][1]. Is it a Bug of Unity3d?


  [1]: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-when-changing-scene-after-handheld-dot-playfullscreenmovie-was-called-app-crashes-on-htc-one-m9-plus

Comment: most likely it is

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
GameObject allObjects;

void Start()
{
    allObjects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();

    StartCoroutine(StartMovie());
}

IEnumerator StartMovie()
{
    foreach(GameObject obj in allObjects)
         obj.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("motion.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
}
```

Comment: Why I need to set all obj to be active?

Comment: Sorry, deactivate them

Comment: Actually I think my question is the same as [the question][1]. Is it a Bug of Unity3d?


  [1]: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-when-changing-scene-after-handheld-dot-playfullscreenmovie-was-called-app-crashes-on-htc-one-m9-plus

Comment: It is very likely, then just have to wait